# How would you do a proof of 'n' is the sum of two consecutive perfect squares, prove 2n-1 is a square number

Tags: proof-writing

'n' is the sum of two consecutive perfect squares, prove 2n-1 is a square number

Comment: It means $n=k^2+(k+1)^2=2k^2+2k+1$, thus $2n-1=\ldots$

Comment: Do not remove the content of your question after getting an answer.

Answer (score 4):

$$n=a^2+(a+1)^2$$

$$n=2a^2+2a+1$$,

$$2n-1=4a^2+4a+1$$

$$2n-1=(2a+1)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

$$n=k^2+(k+1)^2=2k^2+2k+1$$
$$2n-1=4k^2+4k+1 = (2k+1)^2$$